# Python thread signaling

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm looking for some help with implementation in python using threading module.

I have 2 threads, lets say thread 1 and thread 2.

I want thread 1 ----> to signal thread 2 to start. 
And doesn't terminate until thread 1 terminates.

Is there a way we can provide a signal from thread 1 to thread 2.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish. What you are probably looking for are `threading.Thread.join()` to wait for another thread and `threading.Event` to wake up another thread.

Here is an example. `Thread2` has an `threading.Event` object which it blocks on (via `.wait()`) until `Thread1` has `.set()` the event. `Thread1` then calls `.join()` on `Thread2` in order to wait for it to finish.

Again, as it's not really clear what you are trying to do, this example is quite contrived.

```
import threading


class Thread1(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, thread2):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread2 = thread2

    def run(self):
        print("Hello from thread1 - I'm now running. Let's wake up thread2")
        self.thread2.event.set()
        print("Now thread1 waits for thread2 to quit")
        self.thread2.join()

class Thread2(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, event):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        print("Hello from thread 2 - I'm now running, but I'll wait for thread1")
        self.event.wait()
        print("Hello from thread 2 - I've just woken up")
        print("Now thread2 is stopping")


thread2_event = threading.Event()
thread2 = Thread2(thread2_event)
thread2.start()

thread1 = Thread1(thread2)
thread1.start()

thread1.join()

print("Everybody done")
```

Which prints

```
Hello from thread 2 - I'm now running, but I'll wait for thread1
Hello from thread1 - I'm now running. Let's wake up thread2
Now thread1 waits for thread2 to quit
Hello from thread 2 - I've just woken up
Now thread2 is stopping
Everybody done
```